# Post CURL request timeout

Tags: php, post, curl, timeout

I'm trying to make a request to other API service that takes a lot of time with no success...

To test it, I created a simple API request like that:

```
function testTimeout() {
    set_time_limit(0);
    sleep(600);
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'ok', 'result' => 'true'));
}
```

If I tried that API request in a normal browser, it works perfect and I always receive the response (for this reason I think that the problem is with my CURL request) With CURL only works if I put less than 500 secs in sleep... but with more I never receive any answer...

Here is my CURL request:

```
    set_time_limit(0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

I always receive: "Operation timed out after 1000000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"

I tried to put more than 1000 as CURLOPT_TIMEOUT with no success...

This is really estrange... I googled it with no success...

Comment: What happens when you try another URL using your cURL function? Same result? - that would mean an issue with your `$ch` function. Try also to use `USER_AGENT`

Comment: Wait, just noticed `CURLOPT_POST` is boolean, so should be `1`, not `2`

Comment: Hi @ScottMcGready! I tried with CURLOPT_POST to 1, set headers like that: 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Content-Length: '.strlen($content)));

and with the user agent like that:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

and is happening the same! Talking about to try with other url I don't know, because I need a request that takes more than 500 seconds (that is when the problem begins).

Thanks!